# Sort results fetched from models related with Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models

I have two models related with `Foreign Key`  and I want to **sort the data alphabetically**.
I know I can fetch data of models related with foreign keys like :

```
follow = UserFollowers.objects.select_related('user').filter(follow = user_id)
```

Now this query fetched the data which I want but I want to sort the result based on first name which is stored in User table. Also If I run this query

`follow = UserFollowers.objects.select_related('user').filter(follow = user_id).order_by('user')`

then it sorts the result on the basis of user id but If I try this `.order_by('user.<any other field>')` then it gives me the error that you don't have choice of this field.

So Please tell how I can sort data of models related with foreign key.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the double-underscore syntax:

```
.order_by('user__username')
```